# getting favicon with cURL - how can I check if a favicon actually exists

Tags: php, curl, favicon

I'm using a combination of Google and cURL to retrive and save the favicon for sites which my users enter in their profile. I'm using the following code:

```
$url = 'www.madeupwebsitewithnoFavicon.com';
$fp = fopen ('img/favicons/'.$saveFileName.'.png', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='.$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
/* Save the returned data to a file */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

I want to find out whether the site actually has a favicon or not so that I can go on and save stuff about it into the database. I've googled but can't find a solution that works for me.

I did see something which looked like it would work for me but didn't:

```
$pattern = '/<link[^>]+rel\s*=\s*["\']?\s*shortcut\s+icon\s*["\']?/i';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
return preg_match($pattern, curl_exec($ch));
```

anyone any ideas? It's all a bit new to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about curling the $domain."./favicon.ico" and test if the http response was 200?

Comment: Or what is the problem? If google doesn't have the icon, the curl gets the default icon. You can decide if the site has some favicon by checking if some hash of the favicon matches with the hash of default icon.

Comment: that sounds promising, except I'm not completely sure what you are talking about, whats the default icon and how can I check it's hash? Sorry for being a newbie

Comment: You can either rely on google and take the icon provided by google or get the favicon by yourself. If google doesn't know the icon or the icon doesn't exist, google provides default icon  with length 726 bytes and md5 = b8a0bf372c762e966cc99ede8682bc71. You can check if the icon is the default by checking the md5 of the result of curl. 

You may curl the page,d find there the tag by the regex you provided and curl the icon directly. But imagine, that the homepage is terribly large and the downloading will use too much time and memory. If I were you, I would not do that.